# How to cue Watson Assistant to stop responding?

Tags: watson-assistant

I want to build an always-on assistant that can discriminate between ambient conversations and dialogs directed at it.

As far as I know, Watson Assistant does not support a wake word. If this is so, I need a way to instruct the assistant to stop trying to match intents when there is an ambient conversation going on.

Is this a genuine issue (and, if so, does anyone have any guidance?), or is there a way to associate a wake word with an assistant?

Comment: Watson Assistant is a chatbot for text input. Do you mean to use it with the voice add-on? You can add wake words in the voice wrapper and send the actual message via the API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a wake word engine. There are multiple options out there like PicketSphinx, Snowboy, and Porcupine.